# Determining size of python data within mod_wsgi

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I have Django app that leaks memory when executing a certain view.

My software stack is: `Apache` -> `mod_wsgi` -> `Django`

The leak does not reproduce by using `./manage.py runserver`, so I suspect it leaks else where in my stack. `mod_wsgi` runs as part of Apache, so in the `top` I see only `httpd` process that rapidly eats memory.

To make sure that its not in my Python app, I would like somehow to understand how much RAM that `httpd` uses is actually taken by my python app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_wsgi in dameon mode you'll get distinct long-running processes for your app.

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Comment: Switching to daemon mode apparently fixed memory leaking - memory footprint for wsgi daemon is the same as in `manage.py runserver`. Thank you!